# pandas dataframe сравнивает значение двух столбцов, если они совпадают, берет значение из третьего столбца той же строки

Tags: python, pandas

```
   A_Name  A_url  B_Name  B url
0  Name 1  url_1  Name 10 None
1  Name 2  url_2  Name 5  None
2  Name 3  url_3  Name 4  None
3  Name 4  url_4  Name 11 None
4  Name 5  url_5  Name 3  None
5  Name 6  url_6  Name 7  None
```

Необходимо сравнить значение A Name столбца с B Name столбцом при совпадени взять значение из A url столбца по индексу и поставить в B url.

вот что я попробовал

```
data_df_name[['B_Name']].merge(data_df_name[['A_Name','A_url']].drop_duplicates(), how='left', left_on = ['B_Name'], right_on = ['A_Name'])
```

оно работает не так как мне надо, вот что я получил

```
   B Name  A_Name  B_url
0  Name 10 Name 10 None
1  Name 5  Name 5  url_5 
2  Name 5  Name 5  url_5
3  Name 4  Name 4  url_4
4  Name 11 Name 11 url_11 
5  Name 3  Name 3  url_3 
6  Name 7  Name 7  url_7
```

вторая строка лишний, мне надо получить вот такой результат

```
   B Name  A_Name  B_url
0  Name 10 Name 10 None
1  Name 5  Name 5  url_5 
2  Name 4  Name 4  url_4
3  Name 11 Name 11 url_11 
4  Name 3  Name 3  url_3 
5  Name 7  Name 7  url_7
```

Спасибо кто поможет.

Comment: Во-первых, приведите код в удобочитаемый вид. Во-вторых, что-значит "лишний"? И почему он лишний? И чем от отличается от первого, третьего и пр? Из вашего описания задачи совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите делать. Что с чем вы сравниваете, в каких двух столбцах, и какое значение "из третьего" столбца вы берете. В общем, немного напрягитесь и перепишите вопрос так, что-бы его можно было понять.

Comment: Да, вопрос непонятен. Приведите ещё пример таблицы, которую вы в итоге хотите получить, возможно, это больше нам скажет о решаемой вами задаче, чем ваши попытки описать её в терминах "берём такие-то колонки и делаем то-то".

Comment: @CrazyElf: изменил надеюсь так лкчше )

Comment: У вас проблема только в лишней строке? Ну дропните дубликаты уже *после* мержа.

Comment: @CrazyElf это пример, данных очень много

Comment: @CrazyElf дроп не помогает.

Comment: @CrazyElf нужно что бы каждый элемент из одного столбца сравнил со элементами второго столбца, если true в третий столбец по этому индексу дрбавил значение else continue

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['B_url'] = np.where(df['A_Name'] == df['B_Name'], df['A_url'], 'Не совпадает']
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло (